# Is there a way to set client-permissions for just one field in an Aviarc dataset?

Tags: dataset, client-side, aviarc

I know you can set client permissions for a whole dataset like so:

```xml
<dataset name="foo" databroker="bar" client-permissions="view"/>
```

Is there a way to set client-permissions on just one field (similar to how other metadata like "valid" can be set for one field)?

Note: this is in Aviarc 3.5.0, so data bindings are not available.

**Update:** The use case I have in mind is a search parameters dataset. If I arrive at the search screen from a certain location then one parameter should be locked, because the search results should be filtered by that parameter.

Creating a new databroker for what amounts to a scratch search parameters dataset, just so I can set the read-only property on a single field, is really looking like overkill.

**Update:** Just to clarify, the dataset doesn't currently have any databroker bound to it, it is just used like a hash to store search parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to work around this by isolating the parameter I want to be read-only into its own dataset, and setting client-permissions to 'view' just for that parameter/dataset.

This does add the overhead of having to add a special case for that parameter, but I shouldn't need to extend it to any more special cases.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't currently a way to set client-permissions on a single column/field.

It should be possible to set a datarule on a column which prevents the column being writable by anything other than dataset refreshes.

When I have individual pieces of data which should be read-only but are included in client-writable datasets, I keep copies of the data in non-client writable datasets and overwrite the client-writable ones when they get back.

Comment: Updated the question to explain why I don't think data rules are appropriate for my use case.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other declarative options outside of building a whole new dataset implementation which allows for per-column/field client permissions (even then I'm not sure how much of the client permissions system is built into the engine rather than the dataset implementation - you might not be able to do this even with a custom dataset implementation).

Is there any problem with handling things procedurally instead? Keep a copy of the locked parameter somewhere else, and when you get back from the client overwrite the client's value with the copied value if necessary?

Comment: see the answer I posted. But that idea of copying the locked value back to the search parameters dataset does nicely handle the special cases I would have to add for having one param in a separate dataset. If you add that to your answer I should be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, data rules have the facility to set read-only on individual fields.  They can be set on a given field for all rows, or on a field of a single row.

Adam has mentioned that creating a separate databroker for this case would be overkill, which is correct.  The DataBinding layer is intended to provide this kind of specialization for certain use cases within your application.

So, you would create a DataBinding, pointing at your search DataBroker, that adds the rule you require to either an existing operation, or a new one that you define. The Dataset is then bound to the DataBinding instead of the DataBroker and from then on is used in the normal way.

The intention is that rules bound by DataBrokers apply to all data of the type supplied through that broker, so would be rules focusing on data integrity, formatting etc.

The DataBindings on the other hand are a layer within the application allowing you to bind rules relating to user interaction with the data, as in your example.  It is expected that there might be multiple databindings for a given broker, each for a different application path or user task to interact with that data in a different way.

Comment: I've just updated my question to note that this is in Aviarc 3.5.0, so data bindings aren't actually available. I also just clarified that this dataset doesn't actually have any databroker attached, as it's really just used as a hash of search parameters which are then passed to the search operation using `<dataset-param>`.